# specify class file destination eclipse ide

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am using `Eclipse - Indigo` for creating a servlet. I keep getting the following `Specify class file destination` whenever I try to create a new servlet.

How do I overcome this?

[image]

Comment: Thanks , but that does not solve the issue?

Comment: Is project One a web project capable of containing servlets?

Comment: What does that mean,this is the Eclipse -Indigo version which has J2EE capability. What do I do in case of this error. Is it missing a class file? I am creating the servlet under my src folder. Is that the wrong destination?

Comment: Your comments don't appear to be in response to anything.  Were comments removed?  Regardless, your question is vague. Please udpate with more details.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. 
First of all, try re-selecting your "Project", which is the very first row in "Create Servlet" window ('One' in your case). It worked for me.

If that doesn't work, give this a try:
Right click on project in Project Explorer. Go to Build Path> Configure Build Path which opens up "Properties" box. In the left-side pane of this box, go to "Java Build Path". Now, in the right-side pane, click on  "Source" tab. Just above the "OK" button, you can see a text-box labelled "Default Output Folder". You can use "Browse" button to set desired location. I am attaching a pic for your reference:[image]

For more details,
[refer this eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm) http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm

That should solve your problem. Hope this helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may arise if you have not installed the "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development" software package. Simply:

- Help > Install new software...
- select "-All Available Sites-" under work with.
- select "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development" package
- install it.
  Restart the eclipse and try again with servlet creation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which was caused by an error in my web.xml (haed an unescaped &).  As soon as I fixed th web.xml I could create a Servlet.